# Internal Reference - Auto Increment field

Tags: python, xml, auto-increment, odoo-9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuAv9.png)

Hello to all,

I need to know how to change the type of the field 'ref' (Internal Reference) from char to Auto Sequence. You can see on the picture the field. Everytime i create a new Contact, internal reference should auto increment by 1. For example first contact, Internal Reference  1 and so on.

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

Crreate a sequence and write it value to `ref`

*XML code*:

```
    <record id="Your_sequence_type_id" model="ir.sequence.type">
        <field name="name">Reference</field>
        <field name="code">Your_code</field>
    </record>

    <record id="your_sequence_id" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">Reference</field>
        <field name="padding">3</field>
        <field name="code">Your_code</field>
    </record>
```

*Python code*:

```
    ref = self.env['ir.sequence'].get(Your_code)
```